# How to debug exceptions

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, visual-studio-debugging

While logging exceptions to a database or evaluating the event viewer is very helpful. Many times we are often left wondering how to reproduce the error so we can debug it.  There are some good practices that you can apply to serialize the calls and then later with some work reproduce the error and ultimately debug and fix.  I am wondering what tools and or best practices are out there to efficiently debug errors to fix quickly **based on collected exception information**. In other words collect information about any given exception and quickly load into a debug session\step thru the code and more efficiently resolve errors.

Here is something I would consider a dream but would be extremely helpful if it existed.

```
try
{
    //Do something that breaks
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    LogExceptionExecution();
}
```

Serialize the information collected from LogExceptionExecution();
Now having the information serialized take the information completely and load directly into visual studio. Visual studio would then create a breakpoint at the start of the method and begin a debug session. The debug session would have everything loaded to recreate what caused the exception in the first place.  This would allow you to debug and fix the error without spending valuable time on how to recreate the environment and load the code used during the error in order to debug and fix code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: They said - `I am wondering what tools and or best practices are out there to efficiently debug errors to fix quickly`

Comment: You can just create a minidump.

Comment: The exception already has a stack trace - is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it does have very good information but in order to debug it, you still need to re-create the exception on a debug session in order to reproduce, debug and quickly fix. I basically want to load the exception and debug and quickly fix.

Answer (score 5):

For your case, you should write a  Minidump file when exception happens. Minidumps are a mechanism for "post-mortem debugging" - debugging your application after it is "dead".  A minidump is a snapshot of the memory of your application, typically taken when it is has encountered a fatal error.

As how to create a minidump in .NET, please read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dondu/archive/2010/10/24/writing-minidumps-in-c.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info! It is very close or maybe even exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This answer definitely requires some balance, minidumps have rather severe problems.  Beyond having to learn the arcana of SOS.  One big problem is that you can't actually make a minidump, you have to make a megadump that includes the GC heap.  That can easily set you back a couple of gigs.  And most severely and unsolvably, you have to have an **exact** match with the CLR revision that the client uses.  Very hard to come by with the frequency of security updates as of late.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, it is painful to match the CLR revision that the client uses.